# Scraping website using Selenium and handling notification

Tags: web-scraping, notifications

#code2

````
       from selenium import webdriver
       from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
       from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
       from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    
    ```
    
    
    ```
        website = 'https://mallcom.in/pages/dealer'
        path = 'C:\\Users\\Wishes Lawrence\\Documents\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver-  win64\\chromedriver.exe'
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
      driver.get(website)
      time.sleep(2)
    ```
    
    
    `  vendors = []
      address_ss = []
      Numbers_s = []
      Emails_s = []`
    
    # Get all countries
       `countries = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="country_div"]/./*')
        print(len(countries))`
    
    
    # Iterate over countries and get vendor details
    `for country in countries:
    
        WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.invisibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//button[@id='allow']")
        ))
    
        try:
            # Try to click on the country
            country.click()
        except Exception as e:
            # If an exception is raised, it means that the notification was blocking the click
            print(e)
    `
       ` # Get the vendor details
        vendor_names = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//p[@class="vendorName"]')
        for vendor in vendor_names:
            vendors.append(vendor.text)
        address_s = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="detainsData_all"]/p[2]/span[2]')
        for address in address_s:
            address_ss.append(address.text)
        Numbers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="detainsData_all"]/p[5]/span[2]')
        for number in Numbers:
            Numbers_s.append(number.text)
        Emails = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@class="detainsData_all"]/p[6]/span[2]')
        for email in Emails:
            Emails_s.append(email.text)`
    
        `# #Go back
        go_back_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//p[@class="go_back"]')
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", go_back_button)
        time.sleep(1)
        go_back_button.click()
    
    
    
    #Print the results
    print(vendors)
    print(address_ss)
    print(Numbers_s)
    print(Emails_s)

`
````